# Pointer declaration (non-volatile memory) initialization (volatile memory)

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller

Consider a structure with the following data members:

```
struct Data
{
   unsigned int  count;
   const char   *Name;
};
```

A variable of type `struct Data` is created later in the code:

```
PERSISTENT(struct Data log);
```

where `PERSISTENT()` maps a variable to the battery-backed SRAM memory space.

When `Name` is later assigned to in the code (`log.Name = "Sensor1";`), where does the character string `"Sensor1"` get stored. From what I understand, the pointer `Name` is stored in battery-backed SRAM, but does the string it points to get stored in MCU memory? If that is the case, if the MCU is restarted, the string gets lost, but the pointer (stored in battery-backed SRAM) still points to that address which is empty now. Would that be the case?

This code is running on an ARM7 microcontroller (LPC2368 to be specific).

Comment: Difficult to say without reference to the specific MPU. The string is by itself a constant object, so if stored in program, or non volatile memory, it should be valid when powered on again. If the value is stored elsewhere and copied in non backed memory at startup, and the location can change, of course it will be invalid.

Comment: LPC2368. There are multiple strings that can be assigned to ***Name**. If the same string is assigned on powerup again, is there a gurantee that it would end up in the same address location (which was stored in ***Name**) before power off?. What should I look for in the datasheet of the MCU to figure out the right behavior

Comment: Pretty much every MCU toolchain made in the past 30-40 years stores string literals inside flash/eprom...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string literals will be stored in the FLASH memory where the `.rodata` segment is located.

Comment: The address stored in *Name, will that be of flash memory?

Comment: Name will  be a pointer to the stringliteral stored in flash. Itself it will be in in specified section or .bss or .datA by default